# Which is an example of a real function satisfying conditions 1. and 2.? EDITED

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to find an example of function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying:

1. there exists $c>0$ such that $$\lim_{|x|\to\infty} |f(x)|<c$$

and

2. there exist $\varepsilon, c_1>0$ and $\gamma> 0$ such that
   $$ |f(x)|\le c_1 |x|^{-1-\gamma} \quad\text{ when } |x|\le\varepsilon_1.$$

Could someone please help me in find an example of such function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any function bounded on $[-1, 1]$ satisfies your second condition: take $\gamma = 1$, $\epsilon_1 = 1$ and $c_1 = \sup_{x \in [-1, 1]} |f(x)|$ (and actually many more functions also work), so any bounded function that has finite limit at $\infty$ will work.

For example, $f(x) = 42$, or $f(x) = \exp(-x^2 + \sin(x))$. Pretty much any "common" function that have finite limit at $\infty$.

Comment: mihaild, sorry there was a mistake in my question. $\gamma$ has to be strictly greater than $0$.

Comment: $1$ is strictly greater than $0$.